# Can we put lightning web components into a Flow?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-flows, flow-builder

I understand you can put aura components into a Flow, but I don't see how to target an [LWC for Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags)s.

Is there a cleaner way than creating an aura wrapper for the LWC?

Comment: I see in the docs LWC aren't available for flows. Shoulda checked there first. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_map_aura_lwc_components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (winter 20' release) add Lighting web component(LWC) to your flow screens.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_solutions.htm

Answer (score 2):

**No.** As of today, Flows are not supported as per the *Unsupported Experiences and Tools* in the [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences).

Your only option as of today will be to utilize an aura component wrapper.